# AEM CQ5 Query builder Multiple Path with Multiple Properties Issue

Tags: aem

Now am facing issue in Querybuilder api while trying with Multiple Path with Multiple Properties. 
Code is attached here what I did. It is working fine one path with multiple properties and multiple path with one property. My requirement is like multiple path with multiple properties and also some predicates

suggestion would be appreciated

```
 Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        ArrayList<Predicate> group = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

        if (null != searchPathList && searchPathList.size() > 0) {
            mapCount = searchPathList.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < searchPathList.size(); i++) {
                //map.put("group." + (i + 1) + "_path", searchPathList.get(i));
            }
        }
       // group.add(new Predicate("mypath1").set("path", "/content/opinion/columns"));
      // group.add(new Predicate("mypath2").set("path", "/content/opinion/books"));
        map.put("group.1_path","/content/opinion/columns");
        map.put("group.2_path","/content/opinion/books");
        map.put("type", CQJCRConstants.JCRPRIMARYTYPEPAGE);
         //combine this group with OR
        map.put("group.p.or", "true");
        map.put("p.offset", "0");
        map.put("p.hits", "full");

        if (!TheCommonUtility.isEmpty(searchKeyWord)) {



            /* map.put("group." + (mapCount + 1) + "_fulltext", searchKeyWord);
            map.put("group." + (mapCount + 1) + "_fulltext.relPath", "jcr:content/@jcr:title");
            map.put("group." + (mapCount + 2) + "_fulltext", searchKeyWord);
            map.put("group." + (mapCount + 2) + "_fulltext.relPath", "jcr:content/@jcr:description");
            map.put("group." + (mapCount + 3) + "_fulltext", searchKeyWord);
            map.put("group." + (mapCount + 3) + "_fulltext.relPath", "jcr:content/@cq:tags");
            map.put("group." + (mapCount + 4) + "_fulltext", searchKeyWord);
            map.put("group." + (mapCount + 4) + "_fulltext.relPath", "jcr:content/@authorName");
            map.put("group." + (mapCount + 5) + "_fulltext", searchKeyWord);

            map.put("group." + (mapCount + 5) + "_fulltext.relPath", "jcr:content/@SlugName");
            PredicateGroup searchpathgroup = new PredicateGroup("path");

            searchpathgroup.setAllRequired(false);

            searchpathgroup.add(new Predicate("mypath1").set("path", "/content/opinion/columns"));
            searchpathgroup.add(new Predicate("mypath2").set("path", "/content/opinion/books"));     
            */

            PredicateGroup searchKeyWordgroup = new PredicateGroup("property");
            searchKeyWordgroup.setAllRequired(false);

            Predicate titleskPredicate = new Predicate("title");
            titleskPredicate.set(JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator.OPERATION, JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator.OP_LIKE);
            titleskPredicate.set("property", "fn:lower-case(@" + "jcr:content/jcr:title");
            titleskPredicate.set("value", "%" + searchKeyWord.toLowerCase() + "%");
            searchKeyWordgroup.add(titleskPredicate);

            Predicate desskPredicate = new Predicate("description");
            desskPredicate.set(JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator.OPERATION, JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator.OP_LIKE);
            desskPredicate.set("property", "fn:lower-case(@" + "jcr:content/jcr:description");
            desskPredicate.set("value", "%" + searchKeyWord.toLowerCase() + "%");
            searchKeyWordgroup.add(desskPredicate);

            Predicate tagskPredicate = new Predicate("tagssk");
            tagskPredicate.set(JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator.OPERATION, JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator.OP_LIKE);
            tagskPredicate.set("property", "fn:lower-case(@" + "jcr:content/cq:tags");
            tagskPredicate.set("value", "%" + searchKeyWord.toLowerCase() + "%");
            searchKeyWordgroup.add(tagskPredicate);

            Predicate authorNameskPredicate = new Predicate("authorNameSk");
            authorNameskPredicate.set(JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator.OPERATION, JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator.OP_LIKE);
            authorNameskPredicate.set("property", "fn:lower-case(@" + JcrConstants.JCR_CONTENT + "/" + "authorName"
                + ")");
            authorNameskPredicate.set("value", "%" + searchKeyWord.toLowerCase() + "%");
            searchKeyWordgroup.add(authorNameskPredicate);

            Predicate slugskPredicate = new Predicate("SlugName");
            slugskPredicate.set(JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator.OPERATION, JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator.OP_LIKE);
            slugskPredicate.set("property", "fn:lower-case(@" + "jcr:content/SlugName");
            slugskPredicate.set("value", "%" + searchKeyWord.toLowerCase() + "%");
            searchKeyWordgroup.add(slugskPredicate);

            group.add(searchKeyWordgroup);

        }

        Predicate notPredicate = new Predicate("hideInNav", "property");
        notPredicate.set(JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator.OPERATION, JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator.OP_NOT);
        notPredicate.set("property", JcrConstants.JCR_CONTENT + "/" + "hideInNav");
        notPredicate.set("value", "true");
        group.add(notPredicate);

        Predicate notMasterTitlePredicate = new Predicate("pageMasterNot", "property");
        notMasterTitlePredicate.set(JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator.OPERATION, JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator.OP_UNEQUALS);
        notMasterTitlePredicate.set("property", JcrConstants.JCR_CONTENT + "/" + JcrConstants.JCR_TITLE);
        notMasterTitlePredicate.set("value", "Master Article");
        group.add(notMasterTitlePredicate);

        if (!ThecommonUtility.isEmpty(author)) {
            Predicate authorNamePredicate = new Predicate("authorName", "property");
            authorNamePredicate.set(JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator.OPERATION, JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator.OP_LIKE);
            authorNamePredicate
                .set("property", "fn:lower-case(@" + JcrConstants.JCR_CONTENT + "/" + "authorName" + ")");
            authorNamePredicate.set("value", "%" + author.toLowerCase() + "%");
            group.add(authorNamePredicate);
        }
        if (!ThecommonUtility.isEmpty(tagId)) {
            Predicate tagPredecate = new Predicate("tags", "tagid");
            tagPredecate.set(JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator.OPERATION, JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator.OP_LIKE);
            tagPredecate.set(JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator.PROPERTY, JcrConstants.JCR_CONTENT + "/" + "cq:tags");
            tagPredecate.set("1_" + JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator.VALUE, tagId);
            group.add(tagPredecate);
        }

        if (!ThecommonUtility.isEmpty(start_time) && !ThecommonUtility.isEmpty(end_time)) {
            final Predicate createdDatePredicate = new Predicate("issueDate", "daterange");
            createdDatePredicate.set("property", JcrConstants.JCR_CONTENT + "/" + CQJCRConstants.ISSUEDATE);
            createdDatePredicate.set("lowerBound", start_time);
            createdDatePredicate.set("lowerOperation", ">=");
            createdDatePredicate.set("upperBound", end_time);
            createdDatePredicate.set("upperOperation", "<=");
            group.add(createdDatePredicate);
        }

        if (!ThecommonUtility.isEmpty(order_by) && order_by.equalsIgnoreCase("cq:lastModified")) {
            final Predicate orderByPredicate = new Predicate("orderBy", Predicate.ORDER_BY);
            orderByPredicate.set(Predicate.ORDER_BY, "@" + JcrConstants.JCR_CONTENT + "/" + order_by);
            orderByPredicate.set("orderby.index", "true");
            orderByPredicate.set(Predicate.PARAM_SORT, Predicate.SORT_DESCENDING);
            group.add(orderByPredicate);
        } else if (!ThecommonUtility.isEmpty(order_by) && order_by.equalsIgnoreCase("oldest")) {
            final Predicate orderByPredicate = new Predicate("orderBy", Predicate.ORDER_BY);
            orderByPredicate.set(Predicate.ORDER_BY, "@" + JcrConstants.JCR_CONTENT + "/" + order_by);
            orderByPredicate.set("orderby.index", "true");
            orderByPredicate.set(Predicate.PARAM_SORT, Predicate.SORT_ASCENDING);
            group.add(orderByPredicate);
        }
        try {
            session = request.getResourceResolver().adaptTo(Session.class);
            Query query = qbuilder.createQuery(PredicateGroup.create(map), session);
            for (Predicate p : group) {
                query.getPredicates().add(p);
            }           
            query.setExcerpt(true);
            query.setStart(startHit);
            query.setHitsPerPage(showMoreCount);
            result = query.getResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution :    map.put("group.p.or", "true"); put this code in top and use PredicateGroup  concept for search path  `{group=group: or=true[
        {3_fulltext=fulltext: relPath=jcr:content/@jcr:title, fulltext=bibi}
        {4_fulltext=fulltext: relPath=jcr:content/@jcr:description, fulltext=bibi}
        {5_fulltext=fulltext: relPath=jcr:content/@cq:tags, fulltext=bibi}
        {6_fulltext=fulltext: relPath=jcr:content/@authorName, fulltext=bibi}
        {7_fulltext=fulltext: relPath=jcr:content/@weekSlugName, fulltext=bibi}
    ]}
    {type=type: type=cq:Page}
    {path=group: or=true[
        {1_mypath1=mypath1: path=/content/week/opinion/columns}
        {2_mypath2=mypath2: path=/content/week/opinion/books}
    ]}
    {hideInNav=property: operation=not, value=true, property=jcr:content/hideInNav}
    {pageMasterNot=property: operation=unequals, value=Master Article, property=jcr:content/jcr:title}
    {authorName=property: operation=like, value=%ajish%, property=fn:lower-case(@jcr:content/authorName)}
    {orderBy=orderby: orderby.index=true, sort=desc, orderby=@jcr:content/cq:lastModified}`